# How to remove MS Word unnecessary html tags using java regex

Tags: java, html, regex

I have a WYSIWYG editor and sometimes users cut and past into it from MS Word. In my server side java I am trying to remove unnecessary html from the pasted html such as:

```
<o:p>
```

Should be:

```
<p>
```

The patterns I am trying to remove are:

```
  //Remove:
  // unnecessary tag spans (comments and title)
  //   <!--(w|W)+?-->
  //   <title>(w|W)+?</title>
  //classes and styles
  //    s?class=w+
  //    s+style='[^']+'
  //unnecessary tags
  //    <(meta|link|/?o:|/?style|/?div|/?std|/?head|/?html|body|/?body|/?span|![)[^>]*?>
  //empty paragraph tags
  //    (<[^>]+>)+&nbsp;(</w+>)+
  //bizarre v: element attached to <img> tag
  //    s+v:w+=""[^""]+""
```

My code is:

```
  Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<!--(w|W)+?-->?|<title>(w|W)+?</title>?|s+style='[^']+'?|"
        + "<(meta|link|/?o:|/?style|/?div|/?std|/?head|/?html|body|/?body|/?span|![)[^>]*?>?|"
        + "(<[^>]+>)+&nbsp;(</w+>)+?", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
  Matcher m = p.matcher(html);
  String result = m.replaceAll("");
```

I get the error:

```
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed character class near index 163
<!--(w|W)+?-->?|<title>(w|W)+?</title>?|s+style='[^']+'?|<(meta|link|/?o:|/?style|/?div|/?std|/?head|/?html|body|/?body|/?span|![)[^>]*?>?|(<[^>]+>)+&nbsp;(</w+>)+?
```

Can someone please advise me on the correct syntax please.

Wiktor has provided an excellent answer; however the colour style is removed and I would like to keep that if possible.

Before clean:

```
notClean: <p class="MsoNormal"><b><span lang="EN-AU" style="font-size:11.0pt;font-family:&quot;Verdana&quot;,sans-serif;color:#006600">Special
Interest Area badges youth members can achieve, supported by Queensland
Environmental Education Team:<o:p></o:p></span></b></p><p class="MsoNormal"><b><span lang="EN-AU">&nbsp;</span></b></p><p class="MsoNormal"><b><span lang="EN-AU">&nbsp;</span></b></p><p>

</p><p class="MsoNormal"><b><i><span lang="EN-AU" style="font-size:11.0pt;font-family:&quot;Verdana&quot;,sans-serif">Joey Scout SIA Badges
(2 hours each badge)</span></i></b><b><span lang="EN-AU" style="font-size:11.0pt;font-family:&quot;Verdana&quot;,sans-serif"><o:p></o:p></span></b></p>
```

After clean:

```
cleaned: <p class="MsoNormal"><b>Special
Interest Area badges youth members can achieve, supported by Queensland
Environmental Education Team:<p>

</p><p class="MsoNormal"><b><i>Joey Scout SIA Badges
(2 hours each badge)</i></b><b></b></p>
```

I tried:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<!--.*?-->|<title>.*?</title>|"
            + "<(meta|link|/?o:|/?div|/?std|/?head|/?html|/?body|/?span|!\\[)[^>]*>|"
            + "(<[^>]+>)+&nbsp;(</\\w+>)+", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE|Pattern.DOTALL);
```

However, the style is still removed.

I had to leave the "span" in as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```java
String html = "Cleaned!<!-- \nsome comment --><title> my title</title> style='OUR_STYLE'<meta ...>";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<!--.*?-->|<title>.*?</title>|\\s+style='[^']+'|"
        + "<(meta|link|/?o:|/?style|/?div|/?std|/?head|/?html|/?body|/?span|!\\[)[^>]*>|"
        + "(<[^>]+>)+&nbsp;(</\\w+>)+", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE|Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher m = p.matcher(html);
String result = m.replaceAll("");
System.out.println(result);
// => Cleaned!
```

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/UKGCxd).

**NOTES**:

- `Pattern.DOTALL` makes `.` matcb any chars including line break chars (so no need to use a workaround like `[\w\W]`)
- Do not forget escaping backslashes in regex escapes, like `\s` or `\w` (in a Java string literal, `"\\s"` or `"\\w"`)
- Do not forget to escape special regex metacharacters, like `[` or `(`, see [What special characters must be escaped in regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399078/what-special-characters-must-be-escaped-in-regular-expressions)
- If a char must be present in the string, do not put `?` after it (as is the case with `>` in your pattern), it makes the char optional.

Comment: Hi Wiktor, Thank you. I have one issue with this though. The colour formatting is removed. I have added the before and after to my question so it is formatted properly. Is there a way to keep the "style"? I tried the above.

Comment: @Glyn Sorry, I do not get it: if you want to keep all styles, remove `|\\s+style='[^']+'` and other things that pertain to "style".

Comment: Hi Wiktor, from my edit you will see there is a "style="font-size:11.0pt;font-family:&quot;Verdana&quot;,sans-serif;color:#006600"" in the original that is removed. This contains the "color:#006600". Can I keep all the "style= ...."? If not (i.e., will break the html) then can I keep just the color "style=color:#006600;" I believe it should end with a ;)?

Comment: Hi Wiktor, I found it is the "span" I need to leave in. I will monitor to see if this causes any problems. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score -1):

I believe you need to escape the special characters `<([{\^-=$!|]})?*+.>`

[Here is a link with more info.](https://www.baeldung.com/java-regexp-escape-char)